# a message from an old friend

Tags: steganography

I got this message from an old friend.
He used to rob banks, and i helped him, but the last time he got arrested.
The interesting part is that the cops never found the money!
Now he sends me this message..

He probably knew the police would read it before sending it to me and made it harder to understand.


I can't seem to figure it out, can you? 

 PS you will get a fair share.

> You have to find my old treasure.
>   Are you in the mood for a riddle? 
>   Very far from the tree in my yard.
>   Close to my newly painted house it will be.
>   When you are stepping in my garage.
>   You know that your basement is bigger. 
>   See the bewildered backyard behind my house.
>   This is the end goodluck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message reads:

> find the tree house in your backyard goodluck!

Explanation:

> The first word on every line from top to bottom reads:
>
>  You
>  Are
>  Very
>  Close
>  When
>  You
>  See
>  This
>
>  Now the first word of the first line is "You", which has **3** letters. Count **3** words to the right to get the word "find".
>  Similarly the first word of the second line "Are" has **3** letters. Count **3** words to the right to get the word "the".
>  "Very" on the third line has **4** letters. Count **4** words to the right to get the word "tree".
>  Repeat the process for every line and the message can be found.
>
>  You have to **find** my old treasure.
>  Are you in **the** mood for a riddle?
>  Very far from the **tree** in my yard.
>  Close to my newly painted **house** it will be.
>  When you are stepping **in** my garage.
>  You know that **your** basement is bigger.
>  See the bewildered **backyard** behind my house.
>  This is the end **goodluck!**

Comment: Great! But where's my share? ;)